# Error message when adding variable to dataframe : error with different row number

Tags: r, variables

I am trying to add an "id" variable to a dataframe (LDN_wards_map) so that I can then merge it with a fortified object (which already has an "id" variable.)

```
#Fortifying
LDN_wards_map_f <- fortify(LDN_wards_map)
head(LDN_wards_map_f, n = 2) # peak at the fortified data
LDN_wards_map$id <- rownames(LDN_wards_map) # first try in adding an "id" variable
head(LDN_wards_map@data, n = 2)
LDN_wards_map <- data.frame(LDN_wards_map$Code, LDN_wards_map$ward.name, LDN_wards_map$ward.code, LDN_wards_map$electorate, LDN_wards_map$votescast, LDN_wards_map$turnout, LDN_wards_map$id) # second try
```

Here's what I get:

```
> head(LDN_wards_map_f, n = 2) # peek at the fortified data
      long      lat order  hole piece group id
1 532097.1 182012.8     1 FALSE     1   0.1  0
2 532104.4 182011.9     2 FALSE     1   0.1  0

> LDN_wards_map$id <- rownames(LDN_wards_map) # allocate an id variable to the sp data
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c("0", "1", "2", "3", : replacement has 693 rows, data has 664,

> head(LDN_wards_map@data, n = 2)
       Code  ward.name ward.code electorate votescast turnout
1 E05000001 Aldersgate      <NA>         NA        NA      NA
2 E05000002    Aldgate      <NA>         NA        NA      NA

> LDN_wards_map <- data.frame(LDN_wards_map$Code, LDN_wards_map$ward.name, LDN_wards_map$ward.code, LDN_wards_map$electorate, LDN_wards_map$votescast, LDN_wards_map$turnout, LDN_wards_map$id) # allocate an id variable to the sp data differently
  Error in data.frame(LDN_wards_map$Code, LDN_wards_map$ward.name, LDN_wards_map$ward.code,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 693, 0
```

Could anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to add an "id" variable to my LDN_wards_map object?

Comment: I guess it should be `row.names(LDN_wards_map)`

Comment: Hi @JaehyeonKim, I'm afraid I had already tried LDN_wards_map$id <- row.names(LDN_wards_map) before trying without the dot but it's not working either. I still get:     > LDN_wards_map$id <- row.names(LDN_wards_map) # allocate an id variable to the sp data
    Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c("0", "1", "2", "3",  : 
  replacement has 649 rows, data has 693

Comment: I'm not sure why but the error seems to be the new column has more records (693) than the data (664) | What if you add the id column as `LDN_wards_map$id <- 1:nrow(LDN_wards_map)`?